# Syntax error on SQLAlchemy with MemSQL

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, singlestore

When I connect to MemSQL via SQLAlchemy(version 1.0.8) I'
m getting an error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`Charset` = 'utf8' and `Collation` = 'utf8_bin'' at line 1") [SQL: "show collation where `Charset` = 'utf8' and `Collation` = 'utf8_bin'"]
```

echo=True shows that in the beginning SQLAlchemy executes the following command

```
show collation where `Charset` = 'utf8' and `Collation` = 'utf8_bin'
```

When I manually run above command I'm getting the same error, but when I remove the characters( ` ) around Charset and Collation, the query run fine. Is this MemSQL issue?

BTW  I'm using default(MySQL) way to connect to MemSQL.

```
engine = create_engine('mysql://root@127.0.0.1:3306', echo=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a legit bug. It appears this was caused by a recent change / workaround introduced in SQLAlchemy in code using the MySQL-Python library. We'll work to get this patched on our side.

Meanwhile, the OurSQL library works fine:

```
  >>> import sqlalchemy
  >>> sqlalchemy.__version__
  '1.0.8'
  >>> sqlalchemy.create_engine("mysql+oursql://127.0.0.1").connect()
  <sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection object at 0x7f382ff19910>
```